# make Attachment is required when subject = "meeting" in opportunity

Tags: trigger, opportunity

how to make Attachment is required when subject = "meeting" in opportunity ? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately an attachment needs a parent id to be associated with an opportunity, and the id is only populated when the opportunity is written to the database.  Thus you'd have to allow the opportunity to be saved without an attachment, and only after that could you start enforcing the requirement for an attachment.

One way to handle this would be to stop the opportunity with a subject of 'meeting' progressing past a certain stage unless it has an attachment.

You can't set up rollup summary type functionality based on attachments, so you'd need a trigger that updates an attachment counter field on the opportunity record when an attachment is inserted or deleted.  Then in your validation rule, if the stage has changed and the attachment count is zero, you generate an error.